# C-Support Vector Classification Comprehension

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a question regarding a code snipped which I have found i a book.
The author creates two categories of sample points. Next the author learns a model and plots the SVC model onto the "blobs". 
This is the code snipped:

```
# create 50 separable points
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=50, centers=2,
                  random_state=0, cluster_std=0.60)

# fit the support vector classifier model
clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y)

# plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
point_style = dict(cmap='Paired', s=50)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, **point_style)

# format plot
format_plot(ax, 'Input Data')
ax.axis([-1, 4, -2, 7])


# Get contours describing the model
xx = np.linspace(-1, 4, 10)
yy = np.linspace(-2, 7, 10)
xy1, xy2 = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
Z = np.array([clf.decision_function([t])
              for t in zip(xy1.flat, xy2.flat)]).reshape(xy1.shape)

line_style = dict(levels = [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                  linestyles = ['dashed', 'solid', 'dashed'],
                  colors = 'gray', linewidths=1)

ax.contour(xy1, xy2, Z, **line_style)
```

The result is the following:

[image: Image 1]

My question is now, why do we create "xx" and "yy" as well as "xy1" and "xy2"? Because actually we want to show the SVC "function" for the X and y data and if we pass xy1 and xy2 as well as Z (which is also created with xy1 and xy2) to the meshgrid function to plot the meshgrid, there is no connection to the data with which the SVC model was learned...isn't it?

Can anybody explain this to me please or give a recommendation how to solve this more easily?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Did you check the docs of ```contour```? This is common input for contour-plots. The lines are not plotted manually and contour takes care here, therefore this kind of setup.

Comment: @sascha, thanks . Yes, I have checked the docs of contour. BUT why do we use xx and xy respectively xy1 and xy2 instead of X and y? I mean xy1 and xy2 are artificial  arrays created from:                                         
xx = np.linspace(-1, 4, 10)
yy = np.linspace(-2, 7, 10)
xy1, xy2 = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)                                                                               But this numbers have nothing in common with our data we created the "blobs" from. So why do we use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with short broad answers. [`ax.contour()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour.html) is just one way to plot the separating hyperplane and its "parallel" planes. You can certainly plot it by calculating the plane, like [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-py).

To answer your last question, in my opinion it's already a relatively simple (in math and logic) and easy (in coding) way to plot your model. And it is especially useful when your separating hyperplane is not mathematically easy to describe (such as polynomial and RBF kernel for non-linear separation), like [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_kernels.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-svm-kernels-py).

To address your second question and comments, and to answer your first question, yes you're right, `xx`, `yy`, `xy1`, `xy2` and `Z` all have very limited connect to your (simulated blobs of) data. They are used for drawing the hyperplanes to describe your model.

That should answer your questions. But please allow me to give some more details here in case others are not familiar with the topic as you do. The only connection between your data and `xx`, `yy`, `xy1`, `xy2`, `Z` is:

1. `xx`, `yy`, `xy1` and `xy2` sample an area surrounding the simulated data. Specifically, the simulated data centered around 2. `xx` sets a limit between `(-1, 4)` and `yy` sets a limit between `(-2, 7)`. One can check the "meshgrid" by `ax.scatter(xy1, xy2)`.
2. `Z` is a calculation for all sample points in the "meshgrid". It calculates the normalized distance from a sample point to the separating hyperplane. `Z` is the levels on the contour plot.

`ax.contour` then uses the "meshgrid" and `Z` to plot contour lines. Here are some key points:

1. `xy1` and `xy2` are both 2-D specifying the (x, y) coordinates of the surface. They list sample points in the area row by row.
2. `Z` is a 2-D array with the same shape as `xy1` and `xy2`. It defines the level at each point so that the program can "understand" the shape of the 3-dimensional surface.
3. `levels = [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]` indicates that there are 3 curves (lines in this case) at corresponding levels to draw. In related to SVC, level 0 is the separating hyperplane; level -1 and 1 are very close (differ by a [ζi](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svc)) to the maximum margin separating hyperplane.
4. `linestyles = ['dashed', 'solid', 'dashed']` indicates that the separating hyperplan is drawn as a solid line and the two planes on both sides are drawn as a dashed line.

## Edit (in response to the comment):

Mathematically, the decision function should be a sign function which tell us a point is level 0 or 1, as you said. However, when you check values in `Z`, you will find they are continuous data. The [`decision_function(X)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function) works in a way that the sign of the value indicates the classification, while the absolute value is the "Distance of the samples X to the separating hyperplane" which reflects (kind of) the confidence/significance of the predicted classification. This is critical to the plot of model. If `Z` is categorical, you would have contour lines which makes an area like a mesh rather than a single contour line. It will be like the colormesh in [the example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_kernels.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-svm-kernels-py); but you won't see that with `ax.contour()` since it's not a correct behavior for a contour plot.

Comment: thank you very much. But to fully understand it, for me there is still one thing missing. You said: "[...]xx, yy, xy1, xy2 and Z all have very limited connect to your (simulated blobs of) data.[...] ". Am I right, that: 1. the only "connection" between my data and the hyperplane is Z with:Z = np.array([clf.decision_function([t])
              for t in zip(xy1.flat, xy2.flat)]).reshape(xy1.shape)
 ? And 2. Z returns for each point in the "meshgrid" wheter this point has the level 0 or 1 --> Z could do this because clf "knows" which point is 0 and which point is 1.

Comment: In regard to your two thoughts: 1) Yes, you're correct. `Z` contains normalized distances of hyperplanes which are "learned" from your data. 2) Partially correct. I would say values in `Z` has 2 pieces of info, the classification and the confidence. My explanation will be too long for comments. I put it in my updated answer.